# C# Winforms Designer calling base property instead of 'new' one?

Tags: c#, winforms, overriding, windows-forms-designer

I have a class that inherits from another class, who has a non-virtual property ("Controls").

Since I can't overwrite this property, Im using the 'new' keyword associated with my property.

At runtime, this property is called as I want it to, in the correct context.

When I open my form from the designer, the designer calls the base.Controls instead of my 'new' control.

Am I missing something, or is this just incorrect behavior in the winforms designer?

Edit, added the code in question for more explanation.  I have the following class:

```
public partial class BauerGroupBox : ComponentFactory.Krypton.Toolkit.KryptonGroupBox
   {
      public BauerGroupBox()
         : base()
      {
      }
      public new Control.ControlCollection Controls
      {
         get
         {
            MessageBox.Show("GOT THERE");
            return this.Panel.Controls;
         }
      }
   }
```

When I get to the following code in my intializecomponent:

```
BauerGroupBox thisBox = new BauerGroupBox()
thisBox.Controls.Add(something)
```

When I add a new 'BauerGroupBox' to my code, it works fine.  However, when I open my code in the designer (even while using the debugging the devenv), the messagebox is NOT shown, and the breakpoint is NOT hit.

When I run my app, the breakpoint is hit.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing something - what you're describing is correct behaviour.

The workaround is to re-populate your new `Controls` property right after the call to `InitializeComponent()`. Like so:

```
public MyForm()  {
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Controls.AddRange( base.Controls );
}
```

However, why are you trying to "override" the `Controls` property? What new, non-standard, behaviour are you after? I believe there is a better alternative.

Comment: Edited my question for more information.

The way the base control is designed, it doesn't want the user to add to the controls collection directly, it wants the user to add it to control.panel.controls instead.

I'm trying to write a 'route through' to do this automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstand how the new keyword works.  New doesn't override the property, it hides it.  If you reference the object as it's base element, it will still call the base property, not your new one.  The only way to use the new one is to reference it as the new one.  ie.

```
public class A {
    public A1 {get;set;}
}

public class B : A {
    public new A1 {get;set;}
}

B b = new B();
A a = b;

a.A1; // references A.A1
b.A1; // references B.A1
```

Comment: I edited my question with a code sample.  I only want "b.a1" to be called.  At runtime, the form calls the correct "b.a1".  The designer however, is attempting to call "a.a1".  I know from experience the designer instantiates an instance of the base class as you design, which is why you cant derive from an abstract base class while using visual inehritance.

Comment: @greggorob64 - Yes, I know.  The point is that the designer works generically by calling the Control base class, thus it will never call the hidden one.  This is why there is a difference between override and new.  They do two different things and you can't make one do the other.

Comment: I guess I still don't see what im missing, this line: 

         private BauerGroupBox bauerGroupBox1;
         this.bauerGroupBox1.Controls.Add(this.bauerButton1);
Should be calling the 'new' property.  Im not misunerstanding how 'new works'.  This is correct calling procedure in this case, isn't it?

Comment: @greggorob64 - What exactly are you trying to do.  Do not tell me you want to override the controls collection, that's what you think will solve your problem.  What is the actual problem you are trying to solve with this?

Comment: I have 3-400 'groupbox' controls scattered throughout my application.  I want to replace every single one of them with BauerGroupBoxes.  

Whats holding me back from doing a global find\replace is that I have to change every groupbox.controls.add with bauergroupbox.panel.controls.add.  This is going to make it monumentally more complicated because I have to add the "panel." into every groupbox.control.add.  If I can have the designer call my  'new' property, it will save me a ton of time.

Comment: @greggorob64 - It has nothing to do with what object is created, it's how the object is referenced.  The designer references things on their base classes.  You can't change this.  Thus the designer only sees the Control class, it doesn't know about either the Krypton one or yours.  It just treats everything as a Control, and since you are not overriding Control (because you can't) it calls the Control.Controls property.  There is nothing you can do to fix that.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I understand what you're referring to now for the inheritance.  I didn't misunstand 'new', I misunderstood that I thought the designer would reference my control directly, and its only referencing it as a control

Comment: The long and short of it is that my goal was to have "groupbox.controls.add" and "bauergroupbox.panel.controls.add" do the same thing in the designers eyes.  that way I could just do a global search\replace and have it work automagically.

Comment: @greggorob64 - So you were trying to overcome poor design with laziness?  That seems like an.... odd course of action.  There are probably many ways to solve your problem without resorting to this kind of hackery.

Comment: My goal is to replace all of the groupboxes in my project with bauergroupboxes. I wanted to make them interchangable so we can view a before\after of this rather large transition.  If could accomplish my goal, I could very easily (by changing the base class of my control), accomplish this switch back\fourth.  You can call anything you want poor design (Im here asking this question to find the correct answer), but its not laziness.

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand your situation, so let me explain what the designer is doing:

First, at runtime, you are effectively running an instance of your `BauerGroupBox` control. (That said, it's also all likely that you are accessing the `Controls` property through a reference of this derived type, namely `BauerGroupBox`, and as @Mystere Man correctly argues, the member `BauerGroupBox.Controls` hides the inherited member (wherever it is last defined) -- it does not override it.

Bur the issue in question is that at design-time, **in the designer of** the `BauerGroupBox` control, you are NOT **"running"** an instance of `BauerGroupBox`, instead you are `designing` a prototype based on `ComponentFactory.Krypton.Toolkit.KryptonGroupBox` and that is effectively the type of the control you are "running".

I repeat, the designer of `BauerGroupBox` does not have an instance of `BauerGroupBox` running, but an instance of `ComponentFactory.Krypton.Toolkit.KryptonGroupBox`. No `BauerGroupBox` exists in the designer, because, well.. you are designing it!!!

NOW, to add a bit more confusion to that (none really, it's all very simple if you think a bit about it,) you will see that if you go to any other designer of any other control, say a form, and then you drag and drop an instance of your `BauerGroupBox`, and add some controls to it, you will your message box, and yes, in that case, just like in the "runtime" case, it means that you are effectively hosting a `BauerGroupBox`... but in this case, you are not designing `BauerGroupBox`.

As other @Dai mentioned, if what you're trying to do is to prevent people from adding controls to it, then you should follow other design plans: for example, override the

```
protected virtual Control.ControlCollection CreateControlsInstance();
```

method.

Comment: At about the 12th comment I did eventually realize the err of my ways.   My goal is still to be able to not have to replace every reference of controls.add with panel.controls.add for several hundred instances.

Comment: I just added another paragraph to the answer, maybe you can override the: `protected virtual Control.ControlCollection CreateControlsInstance()` method. In it, you would return an instance of class that derived from `Control.ControlCollection` and that "knnows" that its owner is of type `BauerGroupBox`. Then you override the real virtual BauerGroupBox.Add(Control value) method and in it, you would route the adding to the parent control. But that's assuming you really want to go that way.